# Small problem with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts

I downloaded this template from the internet, but now I don't get it to run properly. Can someone with more experience give me a hand? I think it is something small, but I can't figure it out.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Plasmati Graduate CV
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (24/3/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:

%
% Original author:
% Alessandro Plasmati 
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 
%
% Important note:
% This template needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX.
% The main document font is called Fontin and can be downloaded for free
% from here: 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} % Default font size and paper size

\usepackage{fontspec} % For loading fonts
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont = Fontin SmallCaps]{Helvetica} % Main document font

\usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} % Formatting packages

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor} % Required for specifying custom colors

\usepackage[big]{layaureo} % Margin formatting of the A4 page, an alternative to layaureo can be \usepackage{fullpage}
% To reduce the height of the top margin uncomment: \addtolength{\voffset}{-1.3cm}

\usepackage{hyperref} % Required for adding links   and customizing them
\definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6} % Link color
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,linkcolor=linkcolour} % Set link colors throughout the document

\usepackage{titlesec} % Used to customize the \section command
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule] % Text formatting of sections
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt} % Spacing around sections

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} % Removes page numbering

\font\fb=''[cmr10]'' % Change the font of the \LaTeX command under the skills section

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering{\Huge John \textsc{Smith}}\bigskip\par} % Your name

\section{Personal Data}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Place and Date of Birth:} & Canada  | 20 November 1987 \\
\textsc{Address:} & 123 Broadway, City, State, Canada \\
\textsc{Phone:} & +1 111 1112\\
\textsc{email:} & \href{mailto:john@smith.com}{john@smith.com}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Work Experience}

\begin{tabular}{r|p{11cm}}
\emph{Current} & 1\textsuperscript{st} year Analyst at \textsc{Lehman Brothers}, London \\
\textsc{Mar 2012} & \emph{Commodities Structured Trading}\\ 
& \footnotesize{Developed spreadsheets for risk analysis on exotic derivatives on a wide array of commodities (\textit{ags, oils, precious} and \textit{base metals}), managed blotter and secondary trades on structured notes, liaised with Middle Office, Sales and Structuring for bookkeeping.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jul 2010-Oct 2011} & Summer Intern at \textsc{Intech Inc}, Chicago \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Received pre-placed offer from the Exotics Trading Desk as a result of very positive review. Rated ``\emph{truly distinctive}'' for Analytical Skills and Teamwork.}\\
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Jan-Mar 2011} & Computer Technician at \textsc{Buy More}, Burbank \emph{}\\
& \footnotesize{Worked in the Nerd Herd and helped to solve computer problems by asking customers to turn their computers off and on again.}
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}

\begin{tabular}{rl} 
\textsc{July} 2012 & Master of Commerce in \textsc{Finance}, \textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& 110/110 \small\emph{First Class Honours} | Major: Quantitative Finance\\
& Thesis: ``Money is the Root of All Evil - Or is it?'' | \small Advisor: Prof. James \textsc{Smith}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0\hyperlink{grds}{\hfill | \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2011& Undergraduate Degree in \textsc{}\textsc{Business Studies} \\&110/110 \small\emph{Commerce Specialization}, \normalsize\textbf{The University of California}, Berkeley\\
& Heavily specialized in mundane paperwork | \small Advisor: Stefano \textsc{Bonini}\\
&\normalsize \textsc{Gpa}: 7.5/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{Fall} 2008 & Exchange Semester at \textbf{University of Southern California}, Los Angeles\\
& \textsc{Gpa}: 8.0/9.0 \hyperlink{grds_usc}{\hfill| \footnotesize Detailed List of Exams}\\
&\\

%------------------------------------------------

\textsc{July} 2006& \textbf{Liceo Classico ``E. Duni''}, Matera | Final Grade: 100/100
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SCHOLARSHIPS AND ADDITIONAL INFO
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Scholarships and Certificates}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{Sept.} 2012 & Faculty of Science Masters Scholarship \footnotesize(\$30,000)\normalsize\\

\textsc{June} 2010 & {\textsc{Gmat}\textregistered}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}: 730 (\textsc{q:50;v:39}) 96\textsuperscript{th} percentile; \textsc{awa}: 6.0/6.0 (89\textsuperscript{th} percentile)
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LANGUAGES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Languages}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\textsc{English:} & Fluent\\

\textsc{Italian:} & Mothertongue\\

\textsc{French:} & Basic Knowledge\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COMPUTER SKILLS 
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Computer Skills}

\begin{tabular}{rl}
Basic Knowledge: & \textsc{php}, my\textsc{sql}, \textsc{html}, Access, \textsc{Linux}, ubuntu, {\fb \LaTeX}\setmainfont[SmallCapsFont=Fontin SmallCaps]{Fontin-Regular}\\

Intermediate Knowledge: & \textsc{vba}, Excel, Word, PowerPoint\\
\end{tabular}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   INTERESTS AND ACTIVITIES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Interests and Activities}

Technology, Open-Source, Programming\\
Paradoxes in Decision Making, Psychoanalysis, Behavioural Finance\\
Football, Travelling

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newpage

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   GRADE TABLES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds}{Master of Science in \textsc{Finance}}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade}&\textsc{Credit Hrs}\\ \hline
Corporate Finance (Valuation) & 25 & 6\\
Financial Statement Analysis & 28 & 6\\
Statistics & 27 & 6\\
Theory of Finance & 26 & 6\\
Quantitative Methods for Finance & 30 & 6\\
Econometrics & 24 & 6\\
Derivatives & 31 & 6\\
Management of Financial and Insurance Companies & 30 & 6\\
Business Law & 31 & 6\\
Investment Banking  & 28 & 6\\ \\       
Behavioral Models for Economics and Finance  & 29 & 6\\
Numerical Methods for Finance & 29 & 6\\
Advanced Derivatives & 30 & 6\\
Fixed Income (Advanced Methods) & 30 & 6\\ \\
English Language & 30 & 4\\
French Language & 31 &  4\\ 
Internship & & 8\\      
Final Thesis & & 20\\   
& Total & 120\\\cline{2-3}
&\textsc{Gpa}&\textbf{8.0}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\bigskip
\hrule
\bigskip

%------------------------------------------------

\bigskip

\par{\centering\Large \hypertarget{grds_usc}{Exchange Program at \textsc{usc}, Los Angeles}\par}\large{\centering Grades\par}\normalsize

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Exam}} & \textsc{Grade} & \textsc{Grade Points}\\ 
\hline
Corporate Financial Strategy & A & 4\\
Derivatives & A & 4\\
Money, Credit, and Banking & A & 4\\
Business Strategy & A- & 3.5\\
& &\\\cline{2-3}
& \textsc{Gpa} & \textbf{3.875}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: The example runs smoothly once I remove all references to the Fontin font (that I don't have). Can you give a hint about what doesn't work for you?

Comment: please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), see [How to make a “minimum example”](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)

Comment: Like @egreg, I changed all the font references to Arial and it runs OK (though the result isn't very pretty). Do *your* error messages refer to missing fonts? If not, perhaps you could post a couple here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reactions!

The initial script was with the fontin font, but i did not have it either. Downloaded the font and then problems started with italic and bold fonts of fontin that i downloaded aswell and are in the correct position.

Comment: @Krijn Saw your comment after posting my answer; can you add the output of XeLaTeX to your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have [`Helvetica`](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1424) and [`FontIn`](http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html) installed (or change all references to these fonts in the example).

Also, ensure that you have the [`xunicode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xunicode), [`xltxtra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xltxtra), [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url), [`parskip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip), [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor), [`layaureo`](http://ctan.org/pkg/layaureo), [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec), and [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) packages installed.

If you're using [TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) you can install extra packages by running `tlmgr install packagename`. Otherwise, you can learn about installing packages from the [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages).

The example worked fine for me, so I can only assume you're missing one of these dependencies. Posting the output of XeLaTeX would help us diagnose the problem more accurately.